# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> Laravel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm trying to use 'datepicker' jquery and this error shows in the console, i searched alot and i think the error in (CDN links), and tried alot of solutions but no way.

blade page that contains the error in the script:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <label for="from">From</label>
            <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
            <label for="to">to</label>
            <input type="text" id="to" name="to">

        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scriptForm')
    <script>
        $( function() {
            var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
                from = $( "#from" )
                    .datepicker({
                        defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 3
                    })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                        to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                    }),
                to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 3
                })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
                    });

            function getDate( element ) {
                var date;
                try {
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
                } catch( error ) {
                    date = null;
                }

                return date;
            }
        } );
    </script>

    @stop
```

the links in the page that i extend in the (head) tag:

```
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

the links before the body:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/6.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    
 @yield('scriptForm')
```

Could you help me

Comment: Does anything else appear in the console, like a failed GET request for the jQuery UI script?

Comment: form:137 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (form:137)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: when i put @yield('scriptForm') before CDN script links it shows that: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Good old jQuery load/Document loaded dance. Are you sure jQuery is loaded and the jQuery plugin is loaded before your code is executed?

Comment: Please how to know that explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by remove this script in ('layouts.app'):

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

this is Laravel default JS file (app.js) in public folder.